# Cannot boot (any more) from MBR SSD drive even if legacy BIOS is enabled

Tags: grub, uefi, bios, gpt, mbr

The situation is simple to describe in fact:

- A MBR-partitioned Kingston SSD of 1TB containing Windows 10 and Kubuntu was **moved to a new (HP) laptop**: in order to boot there, **legacy support had to be enabled; after that, it worked fine**. It stopped working though after trying to install a new OS (Fedora: its installer for some reason was trying to install in UEFI mode it seems) which resulted in losing grub. I was not able to restore grub on the Kingston SSD inside the HP laptop.
- Trying to go back to the old working setting **I've moved back the SSD to the old laptop** (a Sony with old BIOS, no-UEFI) and there I have  installed Fedora and Solus (both KDE) beside previous Windows 10 and Kubuntu (because I'm looking for a long-term KDE Linux and I need to test a few). I have also restored grub onto the Kubuntu partition as it was initially. **All goes well on the Sony** with this 4-OS setting, no problem.
- ***Moving again the SSD to the HP laptop**, it isn't seen as if the legacy support were not enabled or the SSD were not connected.*
- The **SSD has no physical connection problems on the HP**: booting from a live USB the SSD partitions are seen and accessible. (Other physical problems with the SSD are to be excluded: it works fine on the Sony laptop).
- **The legacy support setting on the HP is enabled and active**: putting an older HDD/MBR drive (Linux Mint Xfce + Windows 10) on the HP **it booots and runs just fine**.

---

Could it be a problem that the SSD now has more OS-es (4) than when the setting *"legacy support enabled and Secure Boot disabled"* worked (2)?

I am even ready to change the partition table to GPT if I was sure it would fix it. But the fact that an old MBR HDD drive boots fine should indicate that I don't need to.

What I mainly want would be to go back to the situation where that setting (*"legacy support enabled and Secure Boot disabled"*) was working with the MBR table on the SSD just as it does with the old HDD that I've tested with.

Given the MBR SSD works fine (grub and all) on Sony laptop (so, all is installed in proper legacy mode on that drive), and an old MBR HDD works well on the HP too (so, the legacy support is in place),  **what could be now the difference between old HDD and the SSD** given one is seen and one not?

---

Reply to comment asking for details on boot error of SSD on HP; it looks like this:

[image]

---

Although now I think grub is fine on the SSD, I have run again `boot-repair` from live usb on HP as if to restore it on SSD. I got errors, pasted on [ubuntu pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PvK8vDBNN6/) although not as severe as I thought: moving the SSD on Sony, the Windows 10 was not available but Kubuntu and other Linuxes were. Booting in Kubuntu (where grub is installed) I run Grub Customizer and fixed the grub list.

Comment: Your mistake was trying to install Fedora in UEFI/gpt mode to BIOS/MBR configuration. Do not force install with errors, go back and check why you are getting errors/warnings. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Since you seem to still want the old BIOS/MBR, always boot in BIOS  mode. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report, do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: On my laptop, I had to change the BIOS to enable "UEFI /Legacy UEFI first" and disabled secure boot. Your mileage may vary depending upon your vendo and the OS your trying to install. Also, I only have one OS installed - Debian 10. I removed the Windows installation. Be careful because Windows may not like the disabling of secure boot - and needless to say if the BIOS complains about having to reinstal the Windows OS - don't change it.

Comment: Also, Linux Mint 19.2 should allow for a UEFI boot with secure boot disabled. If you look in the /boot there should have both  "/boot/grub" and "/boot/efi" directories. But then that may depend upoon choices made during the install. I'm running Debian 10 or Buster which I believe is equivalent to Ubuntu 20.

Comment: @CinaedSimson - Please see all details. No problems with Windows. The legacy support is enabled. After the legacy support was enabled initially on the HP the MBR drive with Kubuntu and Windows had no problems at all. That "legacy support" stopped working after losing grub during Fedora installation. I have now a working MBR drive (works on old bios Sony) that should work on UEFI HP with legacy enabled, as it it did before. Only it doesn't, as if the BIOS setting was fake.

Comment: @oldfred - I have updated the question into a more concise form. `Fedora in UEFI/GPT mode`: the default install settings reported no errors (said nothing about UEFI mode). Please see details in updated Q. The MBR SSD works fine (grub and all) on Sony laptop (so, all is installed in proper legacy mode on that drive), and an old MBR HDD works well on the HP too (so, the legacy support is in place). **What could be now the difference between old HDD and the SSD** given one is seen and one not?

Comment: What do you mean by "it stopped working"? Boot-loop, a black screen, a blinking underscore, device not selectable via firmware at all?

Comment: @Hermann - Grub was lost after Fedora installation failure on the HP. But I have fixed that after moving the SSD back on the old Sony. The SSD works fine on Sony (so no grub problems) and an old MBR HDD works fine on HP (so no legacy problem, the setting is active). The old Fedora installation problem should be absent now. But HP still doesn't see the SSD: which is odd given it does see other MBR drive and all drives work/boot on old Sony. I'll add picture with boot error.

Comment: I am confused by the choice of words "HP still doesn't see the SSD". The firmware cannot access the SSD itself? Or rather it succeeds in accessing the SSD, but fails to find the MBR bootloader? In case of the latter, you should be able to unmount and remove the ESP (if it still exists on the SSD) and then use `grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdx` to re-install GRUB into the MBR.

Comment: @Hermann  - `The firmware cannot access the SSD itself? Or rather it succeeds in accessing the SSD, but fails to find the MBR bootloader?` How can I tell that? The SSD with HP gives the black screen I've posted. But on the Sony it all works, the grub is fine, I can select among 4 OS-es. Also, on HP an old MBR-HDD works, which means the problem is with the SSD not the legacy settings of HP. But what could be wrong on the SSD given it works fine on Sony laptop?

Comment: Try to bring up the firmware's boot device selection menu. You should be able to select the SSD in non-EFI mode explicitly.

Comment: @Hermann - I have tried that, under "Boot Menu (F9)" there is an option "Legacy Kingston" but that does nothing. I'm not surprised: the old MBR-HDD boots fine on the same HP without the need for that (only for the "legacy support"). I'm thinking about trying again to re-install grub onto SSD from a live usb on HP. It sounds illogical though: the SSD grub is fine on Sony. But what else to do?

Comment: Put [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) on a USB 
thumbdrive and try to boot one of your Linux installations from it. Once booted, reinstall GRUB. Also check if there's a BIOS update available for your model.

Comment: What's the logic behind Super Grub solution? Never updated BIOS, that can be risky and I *know* that is not the problem (see the last points in the question). All OSes on the SSD are bootable on a different machine.

Comment: That you can boot the disk in a different computer could indicate that there might be a problem with your HP BIOS. There's a reason why BIOS updates are released. If you are able to boot with Super Grub2 Disk means the problem is probably fixable.

Comment: SuperGrub is good for booting a system that has grub issues, if rest of system is ok. I prefer Boot-Repair's report to see grub boot issues, but its most frequent fix is a grub reinstall or update which if you can boot with SuperGrub can just do from inside your install.

Comment: @Freddy - That very SSD was able to boot with the same HP BIOS (before that Fedora error) based on enabling "legacy support". Based on the same setting, an old MBR HDD can boot just now with that HP BIOS (which works with other drives, like a 250GB SSD nvme etc). So most likely there is a hidden problem with the SSD. I'm hesitating between reformatting it to GPT and buying a new drive for HP (keeping this SSD for old Sony).